# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3

Tags: java, string, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

When I'm compiling and running my tests,
this message appears:
`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3`

I think I've done something wrong with the substrings, but I can't figure out where.

This should be tested:

```
Argument for parsePathname: .mp3
Output getAuthor: empty String
Output getTitle: empty String
```

This is my code:

```
public void parseFilename(String filename)
{
    //Dateiendung entfernen
    int ending;
    ending = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
    filename = filename.substring(0,ending);
    filetype = filename.substring(filename.length()-3);


    //Abfrage, ob Bindestrich(hyphen) vorhanden
    //i+1 ist Position vom Bindestrich
    boolean has_hyphen = false;
    int i;


    for(i=0; i<filename.length(); i++)
    {
        if(filename.charAt(i) == ' ' && filename.charAt(i+1) == '-' && filename.charAt(i+2) == ' ')
        {
            has_hyphen = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!has_hyphen || (filename.length() == 1 && filename.charAt(0) == '-'))
    {
        author ="";
        title = filename;
    }


    if (filename.length() == 0 || (filename.charAt(0) == ' ' && filename.charAt(1) == '-' && filename.charAt(2) == ' '))
    {
        author = "";
        title = "";
    }

    if (has_hyphen)
    {
        author = filename.substring(0,i);
        author = author.trim();
        title = filename.substring(i+2);
        title = title.trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that your exception occurs here:

```
ending = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
filename = filename.substring(0,ending);
filetype = filename.substring(filename.length()-3);  //<- Here
```

If `.` is the first char of the filename (eg. `".mp3"`), the index will be `0` and the substring afterwards will be a string of size 0.
Then you call `substring` with `-3` and it throws a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Make sure the string contain more than just the file type.

If you know that the input parameter always will contain a file extension you could prevent it like this:

```
ending = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
if(ending == 0) {
    filetype = filename;
    filename = "";
 } else {
    ...
```

You should get the `filetype` before you remove it to get the filename. After this line:

```
filename = filename.substring(0,ending);
```

`filename` no longer contains the file extension.